# Limit supremum of two sets

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $E$ and $F$ be two subsets of $\mathbb R$ and define, $E+F:=\{a+b:a\in E, b\in F\}$. Then prove or disprove:

$$\limsup(E+F)\le \limsup(E)+\limsup(F).$$

I know that the result is true for two sequences. That is, $$\limsup_{n\to \infty}(x_n+y_n)\le\limsup_{n \to \infty} x_n+\limsup_{n \to \infty} y_n.$$
But I am unable to prove for sets. However, I have tried with some examples, which satisfies the relation. That's why my initial guess is the result is true.
Any help please?

Comment: How are you defining lim sup of a subset of R? Is it just the natural generalization of the definition of lim sup of a sequence?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists $e\in E$ with $e > \epsilon$.
Then, clearly, lim sup $E = \infty$, and the claim is true. The reason for this is that your subset implicitly comes sorted - think hard and critically about this.

Otherwise, $E$ and $F$ are both bounded above, let's say tightly by $e$ and $f$. But then you obviously get equality, $e+f=e+f$.

Hence, for $E,F \subset \mathbb R$, lim sup$(E+F) \le $ lim sup$(E)\ +$ lim sup$(F)$.

Comment: It's basically trivial because lim sup E = sup E because E subset R. How else would you possibly define lim sup E?